# Can I use code snippets in a Visual Studio configuration file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

I'd like to prevent looking up a piece of configuration code every time I create a new application. Therefore I thought of using a code snippet, but I can't seem to find out how to use snippets in a configuration file.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your configuration file is XML format, you could create code snippets for XML language. You can make it similarly a creating basic code snippet only by specifying the XML language. For more, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165397%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).